# prevent deletion of existing data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to allow read and write but not delete existing nodes.
these are the rules I have but is still allowing to delete (update)

```
"messages_test": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
    "$message": {
        ".write": "false",
    }
},
```

[image: firebase]

this is how I´m removing the node (succesffuly, but i should get permission denied instead)

```
    firebase.database().ref('messages_test').child(id).remove()
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing the 'the `".validate"` on `"message"` works just fine if a message is longer than 2 characters it fails.' Can you show in code what write is allows that should be reject (or vice versa)?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I just simplified it a ittle bit and removed the validation. I want to insert messages into /messages_test but want to prevent deletion

Comment: Thanks for that. Same question though: can you show in code what write is allows that should be reject (or vice versa)? Preferably with only hard-coded values, so that we can run the code to reproduce.

Comment: just simulator for now. take a look at the screenshot I added.

Comment: Once you allow access to a node, it applies to that entire node, and you can't reject that in a deeper child of that node.

Comment: Good catch Doug. @handsome: the initial rules you posted had a `.validate` at the lower level, and validation rules **can** reject higher-level permissions. But when using only `.write` rules, the `".write": true` cannot be overridden at a lower level.

Comment: true. I edited and then added the answer. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the way. restricting the write for existing data

```
"messages_test": {
    ".read": "true",
    "$message": {
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"messages_test": {
    ".read": "true",
    "$message": {
      ".write": "newData.exists()",
    }
},
```